# query for multiple value using single query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an array var items = ['2016','2015','2014','2013','2012']

```
 Instead of each hit with mongodb -->
 db.coll.find({"year":2016});
 db.coll.find({"year":2015})
 db.coll.find({"year":2014})
```

can i get the value in single hit like jdbc query.

Comment: The very top search result of ["mongodb query an array of values"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+query+for+array+of+vaues&ie=utf-8) should point you to [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)